# Novel about a man abducted to be a soldier

Tags: story-identification, novel

He and the other abductees, human and alien, fight against each other in wars on a planet(s) to entertain their captors.  He eventually becomes an important part of a successful revolt.
The protagonist is Brazilian or of Brazilian descent.
The writer is/was known for works of fantasy rather than sci-fi.
It was published in the '70s, '80s, or '90s.

Comment: ‘Brazilian’ and ‘writer known for fantasy’ weakly suggest the Viagens Interplanetarias stories of L.Sprague de Camp, all of which have titles of the form *The [noun] of [name beginning with Z]*; does that ring a bell?

Comment: None of the novels or novellas listed in the Wiki entry about the VI series appear to have a plot that is close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Off on a tangent, I think it was LSdC who wrote a well-argued essay about how a sword similar to the modern fencing saber would be the ideal weapon for melee combat.